# How to fadeIn and fadeOut individual Div elements created with foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop and this creates multiple `div` elements.

I added an `onClick` event when user clicks on the `div` it is doing `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`.

The problem is, that all of the `div's` obvouisly have same `id` and when I click on one of the `div's` it is fade in and fade out only the first div element.

I don't really know how to fade in and fade out them individually.

I have added my code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yyq0t08/)

```js
  function showItems() {
    var x = document.getElementById('showItemDiv');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row rounded-top" style="margin-top:5px;background-color:lightblue;padding:5px;" onclick="showItems()">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Item Name:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <span class="" id="">Item 1</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="showItemDiv" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;background-color: #FFE4E1;padding:5px;">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

        <div class="row">
          <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Time Setup:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <p>
            <span class="" id="id">1</span>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row rounded-top" style="margin-top:5px;background-color:lightblue;padding:5px;" onclick="showItems()">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Item Name:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <span class="" id="">Item 2</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="showItemDiv" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;background-color: #FFE4E1;padding:5px;">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

        <div class="row">
          <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Time Setup:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <p>
            <span class="" id="id">2</span>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any click handling, nor fading code.

Comment: Are you sure you want `jQuery` as a tag?  You appear to be using vanilla JavaScript.  Also, please note that for your HTML to be valid `id`s _must be unique_ -- having duplicates could yield some weird problems...

Comment: As already mentioned your IDs need to be unique (if you use them). You should be able to change them to class="showItemDiv" instead and change it to x = document.getElementsByClassName("showItemDiv") and then loop through those and change the display style.

Comment: Why are you using inline styles when those same elements have classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use same id for multiple elements. Id for each element should always be unique. If you use same id the selector returns only the first element with matching id. 
You should use class with same name.

For each element clicked you can find its parent and for that you can find a child with required class and toggle its visibility.

```js
  function showItems(ev) {
    var x = $(ev.target).parents('.row.rounded-top').find('.showItemDiv');
    $(x).toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row rounded-top" style="margin-top:5px;background-color:lightblue;padding:5px;" onclick="showItems(event)">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Item Name:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <span class="" id="">Item 1</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="showItemDiv" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;background-color: #FFE4E1;padding:5px;">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

        <div class="row">
          <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Time Setup:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <p>
            <span class="" id="id">1</span>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row rounded-top" style="margin-top:5px;background-color:lightblue;padding:5px;" onclick="showItems(event)">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Item Name:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <span class="" id="">Item 2</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="showItemDiv" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;background-color: #FFE4E1;padding:5px;">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

        <div class="row">
          <span class="" style="font-size:10px;">Time Setup:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <p>
            <span class="" id="id">2</span>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Understood, the duplicate ID's are the Problem.

Comment: I have made a working  snippet from your code, you can use that for reference. Consider accepting the answer if it helps, Cheers!

Comment: This snippet is behaving the same way.

Comment: It is showing both the divs. your snippet was showing only one div. isn't that what you want?

Comment: Actually, I want to click on one div and show the hidden div for this item, same for the other. Similar to a collapse effect.

Comment: @Cyber I have updated my code, so you can use it now.

Comment: Thats the one. Thank you so much.